# Convergence of a sequence $a_n$

Tags: sequences-and-series

For $\theta \in \left]0,\pi\right[$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}^{*}$, I'm asked whether the convergence of
$$ 
a_n=\left(n! \prod_{k=1}^{n}\sin\left(\frac{\theta}{k}\right)\right)^{1/n}
$$
What I've tried is to transform (if i'm right) $a_n$ into
$$
\ln\left(a_n\right)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\ln\left(k\sin\left(\frac{\theta}{k}\right)\right)
$$
I've proven that
$$
\ln\left(k\sin\left(\frac{\theta}{k}\right)\right)=\ln\left(\theta\right)-\frac{\theta^2}{6k^2}+o\left(\frac{1}{k^2}\right)
$$
So I found convergence in the case $\theta=1$, but with divergence of the series when $\theta \ne 1$ I can't conclude about the convergence of $\ln\left(a_n\right)$.

Furthermore, is it possible to find the limit of $a_n$ ?

Comment: Still when $k \rightarrow +\infty$ we can deduce whether $\sum \ln\left(\dots\right)$ converges or not, if it does, then we have convergence of $a_n$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since $\lim\limits_{k\rightarrow +\infty}{\ln\left(k\sin\left(\frac{\theta}{k}\right)\right)=\ln\theta}$, by Cesaro's theorem you have that 
$$ \lim\limits_{n\rightarrow +\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n{\ln\left(k\sin\left(\frac{\theta}{k}\right)\right)}=\ln\theta $$